# How can i catch customer_save_after_data_object after saving account information in frontend?

Tags: event-observer, customer

How can i catch customer_save_after_data_object 
after saving account information in frontend?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Answer (score 0):

To get customer information after account register, you can used this event.

```
customer_register_success
```

The implementation are diffrent based on magento version.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options available:
1. Plugin &
2. Observer

Example :
1. Getting customer object after saving using plugin

**step i. Create di.xml in etc/frontend**

> [Project_DIR]/app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
        <plugin name="[Your_Plugin_Name]" type="[Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin\CustomerAfterSave" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**step ii. Define the plugin class in Plugin/[Plugin_Class_Name].php**

> [Project_DIR]/app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Plugin/CustomerAfterSave.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;

/**
 * Class CustomerAfterSave
 * @package [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin
 */
class CustomerAfterSave
{  
    /**
     * @param CustomerRepository $subject
     * @param $savedCustomer
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterSave(
        CustomerRepository $subject,
        $savedCustomer
    ) {
        /**
         * $savedCustomer is your saved customer object.
         */
        $customerId = $savedCustomer->getId();
        $customerFirstName = $savedCustomer->getFirstName();

        /**
         * For the list of available methods
         * Refer : Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
         * 
         * If you want to use getData method then you need to load customer model using the
         * $customerId 
         */
        return $savedCustomer;
    }
}
```

If you want to use observer let me know I will post the process.

Answer (score 0):

To get data with observer You can do like I described here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299114/77243

Just simply change event name in `events.xml` file.