# Magento 2 - Event after customer edit Account Information

Tags: magento2, event-observer, frontend, customer-account, edit

I need to add some custom logic in my extension after Editing Account Information, It should not trigger at Change Password or Edit Address.

Will `customer_account_edited` work.

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'customer_account_edited',
        ['email' => $customerCandidateDataObject->getEmail()]
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use it (will work).
Magento 2 event "**customer_account_edited**" is official/legal event name.

In Your module add this event into your events.xml file.
For example: **VendorName/ModuleName/etx/frontend/events.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_account_edited">
        <observer name="VendorModuleEditAccount" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\EditCustomer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create needed file EditCustomer.php which gets data from observer.
For example: **VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/EditCustomer.php**

```
<?php

declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class EditCustomer implements ObserverInterface
{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
       try {
            $editedCustomerEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getEmail();
            $this->logger->info($editedCustomerEmail);
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             $this->logger->critical('Error message', ['exception' => $e]);
         }

    }
}
```

Upgrade Your modules and clear cache with commands in terminal:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

---

Go to frontend, login or create new account. Edit account.
Go to /var/log/info.log
There You'll see "**test@testemail.com [] []**"

Please note that there is no point to print "**$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()**", cause observer not output all customer info after "customer_account_edited" event. It only outputs email address (that's why I logged only email address).
If You'll print out all $observer You'll get

```
object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)#1529 (1) { ["_data":protected]=> array(2) { ["event"]=> object(Magento\Framework\Event)#1398 (2) { ["_observers":protected]=> object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer\Collection)#1575 (1) { ["_observers":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["_data":protected]=> array(2) { ["email"]=> string(18) "test@testemail.com" ["name"]=> string(23) "customer_account_edited" } } ["email"]=> string(18) "test@testemail.com" } }
```

Tested with Magento 2.3.0

Comment: But it is not working in 2.3.5